# How do I stack the rectangle on the image and have it move up?

Tags: java, image, javafx, fxml, rectangles

I have this image called moneyLadder:

[image: MoneyLadder]

**Note: In the program, the image is not that size. It's much smaller**

and then, at the bottom of the money ladder, I also have a golden rectangle that I want to appear on the number 1 and have it increase as the user progresses. Now, The way I have design the layout is in a FXML file with the root element being a gridpane. I've tried to maybe use the X and Y variable in the rectangle to see if I could move it but that didn't work. Is there any way I could possibly make this work with he way I've design my layout?

**For convenience, The rectangle and the image are located at the bottom of the FXML File.**

**FXML File**

```
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.net.URL?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>

<GridPane  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" vgap="25"  fx:controller="millionairetriviagame.GameScreenController">
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@BackgroundImages.css"/>
    </stylesheets>
    <stylesheets>
        <URL value="@ButtonLayout.css"/>
    </stylesheets>
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints vgrow="ALWAYS" percentHeight="55" />
    </rowConstraints>
    <children>
        <VBox spacing="15" >
            <children>
                <Button fx:id="AudienceButton" onAction="#chooseLifeline"  prefHeight="70" prefWidth="70">
                    <shape>
                        <javafx.scene.shape.Circle radius="1" /> 
                    </shape>
                    <graphic>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="70" fitWidth="70" scaleX="1.2" scaleY="1.2"  smooth="true" >
                            <image>
                                <Image url="@ImageFiles/AudienceButton.png"/>
                            </image>    
                        </ImageView>
                    </graphic>
                </Button>
                <Button fx:id="Button5050" onAction="#chooseLifeline"  prefHeight="70" prefWidth="70">
                    <shape>
                        <javafx.scene.shape.Circle radius="1" /> 
                    </shape>
                    <graphic>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="70" fitWidth="70" scaleX="1.25" scaleY="1.25"  smooth="true" >
                            <image>
                                <Image url="@ImageFiles/5050Button.png"/>
                            </image>    
                        </ImageView>
                    </graphic>
                </Button>
                <Button fx:id="PhoneButton" onAction="#chooseLifeline"  prefHeight="70" prefWidth="70" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
                    <shape>
                        <javafx.scene.shape.Circle radius="1" /> 
                    </shape>
                    <graphic>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="70" fitWidth="70" scaleX="1.25" scaleY="1.25"  smooth="true" >
                            <image>
                                <Image url="@ImageFiles/PhoneAFriendButton.png"/>
                            </image>    
                        </ImageView>
                    </graphic>
                </Button>
            </children>
        </VBox>
        <VBox GridPane.columnIndex="1" alignment="TOP_CENTER" >
            <children>
                <ImageView fitHeight="300" fitWidth="300"  smooth="true">
                    <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets>
                            <right>
                                125
                            </right>
                        </Insets>
                    </VBox.margin>
                    <image>
                        <Image url="@ImageFiles/MillionaireLogo1.png"/>
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
            </children>
        </VBox >
        <VBox GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" alignment="CENTER" >
            <children>
                <ImageView fitHeight="200" fitWidth="700" smooth="true">
                    <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets>
                            <right>
                                75
                            </right>
                        </Insets>
                    </VBox.margin>
                    <image>
                        <Image url="@ImageFiles/QuestionFrame.png"/>
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
            </children>
        </VBox>
        <HBox GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnIndex="1" spacing="140" >
            <children>
                <Button prefHeight="30" prefWidth="200" id="ButtonLayout">
                    <shape>
                        <javafx.scene.shape.SVGPath content="
                       m181,299l220,1l49,-28l-52,-28l-219,-1l-44,28l46,28z" /> 
                    </shape>
                    <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets >
                            <left>
                                80
                            </left>
                        </Insets>
                    </HBox.margin>
                </Button>
                <Button prefHeight="30" prefWidth="200" id="ButtonLayout">
                    <shape>
                        <javafx.scene.shape.SVGPath content="
                         m181,299l220,1l49,-28l-52,-28l-219,-1l-44,28l46,28z"  /> 
                    </shape>
                </Button>
            </children>
        </HBox>
        <HBox GridPane.rowIndex="3" GridPane.columnIndex="1" spacing="140">
            <children>
                <Button prefHeight="30" prefWidth="200" id="ButtonLayout" >
                    <shape>
                        <javafx.scene.shape.SVGPath content="
                         m181,299l220,1l49,-28l-52,-28l-219,-1l-44,28l46,28z"  /> 
                    </shape>
                    <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets >
                            <left>
                                80
                            </left>
                        </Insets>
                    </HBox.margin>
                </Button>
                <Button prefHeight="30" prefWidth="200" id="ButtonLayout">
                    <shape>
                        <javafx.scene.shape.SVGPath content="
                        m181,299l220,1l49,-28l-52,-28l-219,-1l-44,28l46,28z"  /> 
                    </shape>
                </Button>
            </children>
        </HBox>
        <VBox GridPane.columnIndex="2" alignment="TOP_RIGHT"  >
            <children>
                <ImageView fitHeight="300" fitWidth="300" smooth="true" >
                    <image>
                        <Image url="@ImageFiles/MoneyLadder.png"/>
                    </image>
                </ImageView>     
                <javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle width="300" height="30" fill="goldenrod" />
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </children>
</GridPane>
```

**Here is a screenshot for reference**

[image: GameScreen]

**Update** I've recently change the rectangle to be semi transparent and I was also able to use translateY to move the rectangle to the bottom(of course that is not what I want but it's a start).

Answer (score 0):

So I guess this is a suitable answer for now.

```
   <VBox GridPane.columnIndex="2" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT"  >
        <children>
             <javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle width="250" height="28" fill="goldenrod" opacity="0.5" translateY="100" translateX="-30" />
        </children>
   </VBox>
```

So I took the rectangle out of the VBox and placed it in its own VBox, aligned to the  center right and used the same columnIndex that the image used. Then I translated it y units down and x units to the left. So I guess each time they answer a question correctly, I will translate it y units down.

Comment: For some reason, if I decide to re size the window it pushes the rectangle upwards. Why is that?